# Captcha not working with IIS

Tags: dll, iis-7, captcha

i m using a dll file MSCaptcha.dll for my web application its works fine on localhost but not with iis server..what should i do to make it work

Answer (score 3):

Solution :

- Select your application in IIS7. Open Handler Mappings under IIS either by double click the Handler Mappings or click "open feature" under Action.
- Click "Add Managed Handler" under action.
- Enter "CaptchaImage.axd" without quotes in Request Path
- Under Type select MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler
- Enter "MSCaptcha" without quotes in Name and click OK

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and this worked for me.

In your web.config, instead of having the path as "CaptchaImage.axd":

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Try changing the path to "~/CaptchaImage.axd":

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler" verb="GET" path="~/CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```